# Calculating days left to a specific date

Tags: bash, shell, date

I'm having trouble figuring out a way to calculate amount of days left to a specific date (passed as an argument). I tried this, however it doesn't even work correctly with any date of 2021.

```
days=$[$(date +%j -d $1)-$(date +%j $now)];
if (( $days < 0 ))
then
        echo "error";
        exit 1;
fi

echo "Theres" $days "left to this date.";
```

Does anyone have an idea on how I could fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems I see.

- I don't recognize the `$[...]` syntax and can't find a shell that does (see the comments, below, where user @KamilCuk explains this further).
- The `if` syntax is wrong, possibly swapped with the previous line.
- Because of the parentheses, what's read as a less-than sign (`<`) is going to try to redirect input to a program.
- The answer will always print out.
- As you point out, there's no chance of a Julian day working with different years.

Try something like this, instead.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
```

Split up the dates for easier debugging, first, and also use `+%s to get "UNIX time" seconds since the start of 1970.

```sh
now=$(date +%s $now)
target=$(date +%s -d $1)
days=$(($target - $now));
```

Fix the conditional syntax.

```sh
if [ $days -lt 0 ]
then
  echo error
  exit 1
```

Put the output into an `else` clause.

```sh
else
```

Since we have the answer in seconds, divide by the number of seconds in a typical day.

```sh
  days=$(($days / 86400))
  echo "There are $days days left to this date."
fi
```

I also cleaned up the `echo` syntax for clarity.

Note that this still isn't *perfect*.  Depending on your definition of "one day," there are going to be cases where the answer from this script differs from what you want; in that case, you'll need to adjust `$target` to match a particular time of day.  In addition, not every day is 86400 seconds long, because of [daylight savings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) and [leap seconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second).  But with those caveats, it should work well enough and adding those to a script sounds like more work than "how many days?" should warrant.

If you want to see the steps it takes for debugging, run it with `sh -x date.sh '2022-12-31'` (with your script's name and date), since the `-x` argument tells the shell to give you a "trace" of intermediate steps.

Comment: `I don't recognize the $[...] syntax and can't find a shell that does.` bash, it is an extension that existed before `$(( ))` got invented. `The if syntax is wrong, possibly swapped with the previous line.` Using `if (( .. ))` is a bash extension that uses arithmetic expression, it's equivalent to `if let ...` with proper quoting. So, well, `<` means less then.

Comment: @KamilCuk, interesting. I wasn't able to get it to run at all. I'll have to dig back into that later. Thanks!

Comment: Most probably because you have `#!/bin/sh` that runs your script under posix shell. Change it to `bash`.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't include full code for simplicity so I omitted `#!/bin/bash` but regardless of the syntax this is exactly what I've been looking for! Also thank you for a deep explanation.